# How to focus first field and select its content, when user clicked on the link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="some-id-1"><a href="http://example.com/some-id-1" target="_blank">Text1</a></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="some-id-1" name="some-id-1"><br>
        <input type="text" id="some-id-11" name="some-id-11"><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="some-id-2"><a href="http://example.com/some-id-2" target="_blank">Text2</a></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="some-id-2" name="some-id-2"><br>
        <input type="text" id="some-id-22" name="some-id-22"><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".control-label a").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().next().find('input').focus();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/EkyCt/1/)

It select the last field in controls group. How should I select the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:first` selector in the `find()` method:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('input:first').focus();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EkyCt/2/).

Answer (score 1):

`.find('input:first-child')` should do the trick for you.

Although it has to be noted that the `for=""` attribute of the `label` *should* do that exact behavior right out of the box.